# Cambio de valor obligatorio a no obligatorio en input

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Hola tengo un formulario y quiero que el campo del mail sea obligatorio en mobile y no lo sea en desktop, lo que yo hice fue hacer dos input uno con el campo obligatorio y otro sin el, y oculto uno u otro segun sea movil y desktop mediante CSS.

Ahora bien esto implica que se hacen dos envios uno con el relleno por el usuario y otro vacio, ya que aunque solo se rellene uno el otro sigue estando ahí porque lo unico que hice fue ocultarlo(pero existe todavia), lo que yo querría seria que solo se hiciera un envio.

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español Daniel, no se si en este caso es relevante o no el código, así que si crees que compartiendo el código tu pregunta se puede entender/solucionar mejor te **recomiendo** compartirlo ! :) . Un saludo

Comment: Hola Daniel. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas como elaborar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Agrega el código para ayudarnos a ayudarte!

Answer (score 1):

Veamos si es lo que buscas:

Podemos crear una verificación con PHP para simplemente detectar si es un dispositivo móvil:

```
function isMobile() {
    return 
  preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini
  |mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
```

Una vez creada la comprobación activamos un condicional en el formulario.

```
if(isMobile()){
    // Muestra este campo para móviles
}
else {
    // Muestra este campo para Desktops
}
```

A ver si te sirve